# get Parameter Value from Servlet to Js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

My program works like this

Servlet

> setAttribute of prID

Js file

> get Attribute and set it to prID field

jsp

> print the PrID

The jquery script is working when it is inside my jsp file but I want to put in inside a js file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var prID = '${BoMPrNumber}';
        document.getElementById('productID').value = prID;
    });
```

I already imported my js file

```
<script src="js/setProductID.js"></script>
```

it only prints = ${BoMPrNumber};

Comment: productID is input field?
What is the problem? Can't understand.

Comment: no its not an input value, but it will set into the value of prID @Sojtin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP code is only going to run inside a file that is processed as a JSP file.

If you put it in a file with a `.js` extension then, under just about every server configuration, that file is going to be served up as a static file.

You have several options to deal with this:

- Configure the server to process `.js` files as `.jsp` files (don't do this, it will cause more headaches then anything else).
- Make the `.js` file `.jsp` file that outputs `application/javascript` instead or `text/html`
- Use an inline `<script>` in the `.jsp` file
- Store the data in the HTML somewhere (e.g. in a `data-*` attribute) and access that from the JS